# The sugar/glucose is one point too high

Tags: blood-tests

I am 60 and I got my first blood test in a few years.
The glucose is 101. the range is 65-100. My doctor wrote this:

> The sugar/glucose is one point too high.   You should try to eat fewer
>   carbs (rice and pasta) and less sugar to help keep this down.

Can I eat potato instead?

Also, any danger associated with high glucose?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you can eat potato salad or not is asking for personal medical advice, which we can't provide. You should check with your doctor to be sure. However, potato salad is almost all carbs just like rice and pasta, so your doctor will almost certainly say no.

Yes, high glucose is dangerous if it becomes chronic. Consider [this](http://www.webmd.com/diabetes/how-sugar-affects-diabetes#2):

> Almost any part of your body can be harmed by too much sugar. Damaged
>   blood vessels cause problems such as:
>
> ```
> Kidney disease or kidney failure, requiring dialysis
> Strokes
> Heart attacks
> Vision loss or blindness
> Weakened immune system, with a greater risk of infections
> Erectile dysfunction
> Nerve damage, also called neuropathy, that causes tingling, pain, or less sensation in your feet, legs, and hands
> Poor circulation to the legs and feet
> Slow wound-healing and the potential for amputation in rare cases
> ```

Your glucose level is barely high at this point, so that's why your doctor recommended diet modification instead of medications. If you follow their advice, you won't have high blood sugar and won't suffer the consequences listed above.

If you want your rice, pasta and potato salad in the future, the best way to get them back is by reducing your blood sugar levels, and the best way to do that is by losing weight and exercising more. It really will make a difference and probably allow you to have potato salad again in the future.